# How Auto bidding works in auction sites

Tags: jquery, mysql, cron

I am having a question about Auction website. I am not asking about entire process as I know that's impossible to answer here. I just need the lead with explanation

Explanation for Autobids booking :-

If user gives the High and Low value for bidding price with number of bids to place in that range. The system should place the bid automatically even the system in hibernate.

For example :-

```
High (Bid from) : 10
Low  (Bid To)   : 20
Number of bids  : 5
```

Let us take current auction price is $11 .Then the machine is active, so it should place a bid with randomly generated time interval.

I did these closely in jQuery. But it should work even it hibernate.

This technique is already used in many live auction websites like

- http://www.beezid.com/

If you login then you can see the machine in auction details page. 
If you have any previous experience please share it. Does Cron job make sense?

My table structure is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218166/mysql-select-switching-rows-for-every-execution).

What technique is used for this? How can I do this?

Comment: why i am getting negative vote for this question ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it's for your own site,  then what I would do when any bid is placed on an item, simply check for other auto bids on the same item and apply any which are relevant looping until all auto bids are processed.

Comment: questions about updating process not about looping.

Comment: I'm sorry if user bid on auctions . we can check is machine is available .if yes then we can place bid from machine. I need to place bidz from machine with some seconds interval. In this case, I think this not possible, I have explanation . Thats welcome

Comment: @gowri: I would say that Jane is correct.  Typically, you will accept a bid from user A that has a top bid ammount and current bid.  Then user B will bid.  At that point, you need an algorithm that will check existing 'top bids' and apply them against the current bid.  If the bid is replaced, you need to check against top bids no bids will replace the current bid (the looping that she mentioned).  You should do this in response to an actual bid rather than having a polling system.

Answer (score 3):

Handling auto bidding should be a server side process, where the server get's the value of your high and low bid, and number of bids your willing to make and saves it in a database. This ensures that while you can go somewhere else, surf to another page, that your wishes will still be carried out.

Now, you say this should be done as a second, by second process, but really on the server side the state does not change each second. The state only changes when someone makes a change (f.e. a new bid is placed.) Once a new bid is placed it will check to see if the price of the current bid is within the auto-bid range and follow the process below.

On the server side, the server will collect all auto bids for a current auction. The price of the current bid will be checked to see if it is in range of any auto bid and it will make a list of all auto bids within the range. From here, it processes the auto bids until the price is no longer within range of any auto bids.

Answer (score 3):

First you need a cron job to end the auction and calculate the outcome. That cannot be avoided.

About autobidding it could be simply run when the user places a bid, no cron needed.
Your script would do:

1. Get the current user's max autobid. (the user that posts the form)
2. In the same script run the competition for this action instantly. It it is logical that you would compete
   only against the current highbidder, because he already outbid the others.
3. Get the user that have bigger max bid (one of the both).
4. Place him as current highbidder and place for bid the "competitor's max bid" + "the min bid increment"
5. Send messages (e.g. email) for what happened to both.

No need of any cronjobs here, all happens instantly

Further if you need to show live biddings, you need an ajax script that fetches the current highbidders in a short period, like 10 secs or minute.

Comment: You're right for things like "You've won!" e-mails etc. then. There you need a cronjob or something similar. But that can be done every 1,5,15 min whatever. This haven't to be done on a second-basis.

The bidding and auction end itself may be very time critical. For auction end a second-basis cronjob would even not be enough. People would contradict when there are bids after auction end - and when it's "only" a second.

Comment: Well for auction ends if you restrict time endings to be every 10 min it a simple cron job would be enough. however i would duplicate the ending procedure with a check when the auction details are displayed to the visitor and trigger it if the time passed but the action is not completed. This will force update before the cron job passed through this action, and the visitor will see the updated information. Else if a visitor sees the page on the 5th min it will show inconsistent information: bidding ended but there is no official winner.

Answer (score 1):

If the client machine is off, then the process is obviously running on a/the server.

Are you trying to add this functionality on your own auction site, or trying to create automated bids on someone else's auction site?

If the former, then you could fire a cron job every minute to see what bids to make.  Or you could have a database trigger that looked to see if someone had been outbid and make a new (pre-arranged) bid on their behalf.

If this is someone else's auction site, the your machine must be powered up to make this request of their server.

(Or, this could just be link spam for the two sites listed...)

Hope that helps.

Comment: it's for my own website,cron job for every minute doesn't make any sense . because auction is for every second.

Comment: Good point.  A background process is called for then.  Either a separate process or a thread in some other part of your system.

Be sure to monitor that it hasn't died (or, for a separate process, put it in a restart loop).

Good luck.

Comment: you would obviously need a cron job to simply know when bidding ends. And it may happen any minute, unless you restrict bidding ends to a specific time. But you can run update for autobidding at the moment the user places his max bid. There are no changes in-between user actions

Comment: @venimus Bidding ends when auction's end date is in the past. No need for cronjob here. No need for cronjob or background process here at all. You may want to install a cronjob for sending emails or whatever later then, but for bidding process it is not needed.

Comment: @Fatal you are right, but what i mean is that you have to trigger some actions at the moment the auction ends, like sending emails to the subscribed users.

Comment: @venimus I commented on your post. You're totally right in this point, of course. +1

Answer (score 1):

I would not use a cronjob or similar for that.

The principle is easy summarised:
Use `new bid` and `new created auto-bid` as trigger - no cronjobs or similar. The leader is the one having highest limit. The current price is the `2nd highest limit + bid-step`.

Consider making a `loosing bid` from the 2nd highest user right before doing the current leading bid. Therefore it's more transparent for users why auto-bid from leader went that high.

You have to think about some special cases when two `auto-bid` having the same highest value etc., but that would make my answer a wall of text. And these cases are easy to handle. (i.e. taking the user with oldest auto-bid creation date as leader.)

And here some reasons why a cronjob is a very bad idea (in my opinion):

- It is slower because it works with an interval. Solution above works with triggers that fire immediatly when needed.
- It consumes more resources than necessary. Solution above works with triggers that fire if and only if something have to be done. Cronjob solution runs over auto-bids over and over again while doing nothing than consuming cpu time, producing disc I/O etc. most of the time.
- Cronjob solution has performance race condition. Job must be finished until next job interval begins. When you have an interval of 1 second every update process must be finished in less a second or they get overlapped. Or you have to sync this ...

And you do not need a cronjob for ending auctions, too. Auctions are ending at a specific date/time and when it is in the past the auction is over. Further bids are not accepted. No need for cronjob here, too.

Comment: yes i agree cron is very bad for this, But I have problem on triggering,like current price: $10, last bidder: 1 if user 2 set a machine with low 9 and high 10. now it should be triggered with out any other bidz. any solution for this !

Comment: Yes, that's why I would trigger either when someone bids and when someone setups a new maschine. Both are triggers.

Simply said: Use all user actions as trigger where current price may change.

Answer (score 0):

For **auto bidding** there will be a field in the **database**.
If it is set for auto bidding we will set a **cron job** run in server which will run in certain period and check the **autobid flag** and update the bid

Comment: yes i agree, But i heard cron is only from minute not in seconds.Auction are related to seconds not with minutes. so how can i update (placing bid) the bid table.

Comment: how you going to close the bids ? when any user login and see the auction you will be checking the auction end date . if it is over they cant bid. if it is less they can bid. at that time you will be checking is there any other auto bid. if yes update that.

Comment: I need to place the bid in live time.

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion is to work out the bidding to each client when they retrieve the html page.
e.g 
When i get to your auction site, your server says that there is a user that auto bids every 5 seconds since 3pm if the high and low is in range and is lower than amount of bids, and if it is now 4:33 pm then calculate the current bid based on time passed since 3pm.

Now the html that I will recieve will update every second on the my browser displaying the current bid, and auto bidding for the previously mentioned user every 5 seconds.
Once I bid on an item the server will retrieve the current bid for the item and returns me as the current bidder, if my bid was the highest, or someone else's bid if their bid is higher.

This will make it seem as though it all happens in realtime.

Answer (score 0):

I may be dense here, but isn't it just

- new bid
- highest Low (brr) wins (for instance: Hi/Lo/Step=10/20/5), lets call it A
- get next highest Low ( for instance Hi/Lo/Step=11/17/6) lets call it B
- set new price to `A(Lo) - ( ( A(Lo) - A(Hi) ) / A(Step) ) * FLOOR( ( A(Lo) - B(Lo) ) / ( ( A(Lo) - A(Hi) ) / A(Step) ))`
- step 'width' ==  `( ( A(Lo) - A(Hi) ) / A(Step) )` = `(20-10)/5` = `2`
- to clarify: target is `A(Lo) - stepwidth * FLOOR((difference between A & B)/stepwidth)`
- `20 - 2 * FLOOR( ( 20-17 ) /2)` => `20 - 2 * FLOOR(3/2)` = `20 -2 * 1` =  **`18`** for A

Or does the bidding *have* to be 'played out'? (or having missed doing *any* action/bids in my life (fixed price or negotiation all the way) am I missing some social education)?

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing but are you trying to write a penny auction with live countdown for closing time and constantly updated bid amounts? With several items on a single page with all this happening?

Best answer: Use iframe for each item on the page, have them refresh every 2 seconds, check the database for info and display bid info in iframe. You can use a java countdown ticker for live close time countdown display in each iframe window as well..