# Mysql select switching rows for every execution

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing auto bidding system,There is a tricky scenario. That is, I want select next machine to bid from "table_machine" on each execution of code.
Which means,  I am picking bids from active (status=1) machine to bid.

```
execution 1 bidz from mid 1
execution 2 bidz from mid 2
.......
execution 4 bidz from mid 4
execution 5 bidz from mid 1
```

after execution 1 if user 2 bidz on live then machine bid should negleate mid 2 and its should bid mid3

I am having two tables

table_bid_history

```
history_id    user_id      product_id         price        type 
1               1               1              10          live         
2               2               1              10.5        live 
3               1               1              11         machine     
4               2               1              11.5       machine     
5               3               1              12         machine              
6               4               1             12.5       machine       
7               1               1              13         machine
```

table_machine

```
mid      user_id          product_id    start       end     num_bidz  status               
1           1                1             8          12        5        1
2           2                1            10          15        15       1
3           3                1            11          16        10       1
4           4                1            11          16        10       1
```

How can i do this , I am feeling this is tricky But there must be way to do this. give me idea please . 
Please advise me ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly you could do this :
create a new fake field on your machine_table and named it `lastSelect` and in your Where Clause Use something like this :

```
SELECT FROM ............. 
    LEFT JOIN table_machine tm ON tm.lastSelect=1
WHERE id = IF(tm.id=MAX(tm.id),1,tm.id)
```

Then update current lastSelect on table_machine to 1